# Grep command to get specific file but it does not work

Tags: linux, grep

I want to display all of the lines in the file `inventory` that contain the word `Straw` right before a space.

The data file `inventory` contains:

```
Strawberry Jam,300,4
Raspberry Jam,1216,7
Blueberry Jam,96,195
Strawberry Compote,49,621
Raspberry Compote,1937,624
Blueberry compote,200,625
Frozen Strawberries,130,1941
Straw Hats,16,2047
```

I have tried `grep ".Straw" inventory`.

Comment: Could you tell us what you mean by "not working"? Is there an error we should know of? A pattern that's missed?

Comment: its an assignment that i have to do and it doesnt consider it as valid answer

Comment: Is your sample inventory formatting consistent (all in one line)? Reading http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324566/command-regarding-about-grep, it is still unclear: do you need your space before "Straw", or after?

Comment: No they are in all different lines

Comment: What research have you done? In particular, I’m curious what gave you the idea that putting a **`.`** ***before*** `Straw` would enable you to match a space ***after*** the word `Straw`. Also, please explain: Are you trying this on an actual system, where success or failure is determined by whether or not a command gives the correct answer?  Or are you trying this on a test system, where you type in a command, and it says “Yes” if you (exactly?) match the command it wants you to give, and “No” if you enter anything else (even if it would actually work on a real system)?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe with something like this:

```
grep -iE '(^|[^a-z])straw ' inventory
```

Lines starting with "straw ", and line matching a non-alphabetical character followed by "straw " (may need to match out numbers as well, ... depends on your inventory file).

---

Update: if you need your space to be before the word straw, then:

```
grep -i ' straw' inventory
grep -iE ' straw( |$)' inventory
```

Comment: nah it didn't work

Comment: @LovyaBirdHasse801: Please stop saying “nah it didn’t work”. Please [edit](/posts/1147621/edit) your question with (1) the output of the command `od -ab inventory`, (2) the output that you want, (3) the output that you’re getting from the command you tried, and (4) the output that you’re getting from each command that’s suggested in an answer. This one in particular, as it looks to me like it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Your command line seems to be ok to me, maybe there's not a space after "Straw".

Example: I created a file with a line with space and another with tab right after "Straw".

```
$ cat inventory
00 Strawberry
12Straw space
21Straw tab
cba Straw
```

Let's execute your command:

```
$ grep -i 'straw ' inventory
12Straw space
```

Now let's execute the same, but with character classes instead:

```
$ grep -i 'straw[[:space:]]' inventory
12Straw space
21Straw tab
```

Comment: nah it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Pipe cat to grep? `cat inventory | grep "^straw\ "`

Could also be achieved with `sed` and `printf`

Comment: nah it didn't work

Comment: [Don’t `cat` a single file and pipe it (into anything)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat)

Answer (score 0):

basicly I'd go with the others and say

```
cat inventory | grep straw
```

as for me this should be the solution. Even if it might be a 'cat abuse'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I have decided to share it with others.
All of them are correct.

1. `egrep "Straw[[:space:]]" inventory`
2. `grep "Straw[  ]" inventory`
3. `grep "Straw " inventory`

But only the last one works for that Linux assignment.

Comment: for 3rd command after Straw  , there is space then use "